# Como colocar codigo html na pergunta

Tags: html, css, div, posicionamento, layout-responsivo

Estou com um bloco de codigo html e preciso por aqui no corpo da pergunta

Comment: Boa noite. oque você já tem feito? edita sua pergunta e posta o código que você tentou fazer para que a comunidade te ajude melhor.

Comment: Estou aprendendo a usar o forum, kkk a postar o código

Comment: da uma olhada na resposta que te mandei, ve se te ajuda

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Coloque o seu código HTML na pergunta, logo após selecione todo o código HTML e clique em `{}`  ou `Ctrl + k`

Comment: Mas a sua questão é de como usar o StackOverflow ? Se sim esta pergunta devia estar no meta

Comment: Para saber como formatar código nas postagens, veja a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). No caso específico de HTML/CSS/JavaScript, é possível (e recomendável) usar os [snippets](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4463/112052)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De uma olhada na forma que fiz, tente entender, e veja se consegue fazer de outras formas para aprender melhor :)

```css
section{
      background-color: red;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      padding: 2%;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
   
      
    }

    div{
      background-color: orange;
      width:47.5%;
      height: 45%;
      margin: 1%;
    }

.box{
    background-color: black;
      width:47.5%;
      height: 45%;
      margin: 1%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 24%;
      right: 24%;
      top: 30%;
      
}
```

```html
    <section>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>

    <div class="box"></div>
    
    </section>
```